# Should I format numbers (financial data) for Arabic localization (android app)?

Tags: android, localization

I have some Android applications about finance (prices and some calculations).  What is the right way to show the finance data for Arabic localization? Formatted as Arabic numbers or "Latin" (١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨  or 12345678)? 
Usually I format all the numbers to user locale, but uninstall rate for Arabic locale is way too high compared to other localizations (except Saudi Arabia). Also I've noticed that many of the developers from Arab countries (on Google Play) do not format the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting numbers in **Arabic Locale** (**١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨**) is considered "going for the **extra mile**" and will be mostly **appreciated** by Arabic natives. Native Arabic speakers **will certainly notice** the product is extremely localized to their needs (in your case financial markets) and you have taken them into consideration.

**Nevertheless,** you need to consider **copy-and-paste** and **form filling** (**mostly they are already taken care of by the OS**). e.g. copying the number "١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨ " shall copy 12345678 to make sure compatibility with other apps. Also, Regular Expressions in forms shall consider the Arabic numbers.

**PS**, make sure the translation is perfect :)